# NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null on Android Studio 3.2.1

Tags: android, android-studio

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\android-ndk-r19-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r19\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/code2/final/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\code2\final\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\android-ndk-r19-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r19\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=arm64-v8a NDK_ALL_ABIS=arm64-v8a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/code2/final/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\code2\final\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\android-ndk-r19-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r19\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/code2/final/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\code2\final\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\android-ndk-r19-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r19\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/code2/final/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\code2\final\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\android-ndk-r19-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r19\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/code2/final/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\code2\final\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\android-ndk-r19-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r19\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=1 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/code2/final/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/debug/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\code2\final\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\debug\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\android-ndk-r19-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r19\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=x86_64 NDK_ALL_ABIS=x86_64 NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/code2/final/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\code2\final\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File

Build command failed.

Error while executing process C:\android-ndk-r19-windows-x86_64\android-ndk-r19\ndk-build.cmd with arguments {NDK_PROJECT_PATH=null APP_BUILD_SCRIPT=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Android.mk NDK_APPLICATION_MK=D:\code2\final\app\src\main\jni\Application.mk APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a NDK_ALL_ABIS=armeabi-v7a NDK_DEBUG=0 APP_PLATFORM=android-16 NDK_OUT=D:/code2/final/app/build/intermediates/ndkBuild/release/obj NDK_LIBS_OUT=D:\code2\final\app\build\intermediates\ndkBuild\release\lib APP_SHORT_COMMANDS=false LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS=false -B -n}

process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, "", ...) failed.

*** Android NDK: APP_STL gnustl_static is no longer supported. Please switch to either c++_static or c++_shared. See https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/cpp-support.html for more information.    .  Stop.
Open File

Comment: Why this is showing up now is beyond me.  Solved with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54404007/how-to-fix-process-begin-createprocessnull-failed-error) post.